# Laravel : Auth check with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5

I have the following code for the url, if url have `invited_by` then show signup popup on the provided page in the link like this `http://streamkar.dev/store/?invited_by=1` , Its basically to show the signup popup.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a = window.location.href.toString();
    var  b = a.split("invited_by=");
    if(typeof b[1] !=="undefined"){
        console.log(b[1]);
        $("#login-modal").modal('show');
        $(".signin").click();
    }
});
```

What i want is that how can we check user Authentication, That if a user is already logged in then :

Show :

`http://streamkar.dev/store`

Instead of :

`http://streamkar.dev/store/?invited_by=1`

Basically The invitation link can be given to someone, If he/she is already logged in then just show the page, If not then show the popup for signup then redirect to the page in the url, Its basically invitation.

How can i achieve that, I am not coming up with some suitable logic.

Comment: Your question is entirely about javascript, but you tagged it with php and laravel, too. And why would you redirect with javascript instead of using the built-in routes in laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like below,

In the `controller`, check user logged AND query has `invited_by` param, IF so redirect to `store` ELSE render the `view`.

```
public function getIndex(Request $request)
{
    if (Auth::check() && $request->has('invited_by')) {
        return redirect('/store');
    } else {
        return view('path_to_view')
               ->with('userLogged', Auth::check());
    }
}
```

In the `.blade` file, render the `modal` html if user not logged.

```
@if (! $userLogged)
    <div id="login-modal"></div> //model html
@endif
```

in `javascript`, show the `modal` if dom has div with id `login-modal`

```
if(typeof b[1] !=="undefined" && $("#login-modal").length > 0){
    $("#login-modal").modal('show');
    $(".signin").click();
}
```

Comment: Thanks bud, I have a question,I have alot of views functions, Is there anyway to create one function or anything else which can be used for every view function ?

Comment: ah its simple you can use `Auth::check()` in `blade` file, or you can use `view composers` https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#view-composers

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is from Controller function store,check if user already authenticated

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    return redirect()->to('store')
}
```